# VB.net won't reference a dll

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference

I'm using VB.net 2013 with an FTDI USB-SPI converter and library ftd2xx64.dll.

When I try to reference the library I get the message 'Can't add reference to ftd2xx64.dll. Make sure the file is accessible and is valid COM component.'

I tried regsvf32 and tlbimp also with no success.

I'm going nuts, so any ideas would be awesome!

thanks

Comment: Clearly the DLL is not compiled into IL nor a COM DLL. You can't just expect every DLL to be referenceable by a .NET project. My guess is that it is compiled into machine code, thus its methods would only be accessible via Platform Invocation (if they can be accessed at all). -- Could you perhaps tell us where you got the DLL from?

Comment: Hi Vincent,  Yea, from www.ftdichip.com They make USB converter hardware. Been around for a long time and dirvers are WHQL.. I tried regsvr32 again with the file in the bin folder and got the error

Comment: "DllRegisterServer entry point was not found"

Comment: They do provide a C# library to got with the dll, with VB6 examples.

Comment: I found where Visual Studio uses a 32 bit version of  regasm. They suggest placing  "%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm" "$(TargetPath)"  in the post build options. But I can no longer find this. It is no longer in the complie properties. Anyone know where that is?

Comment: You are using the wrong one. *FTDI have provided a managed .NET wrapper class for the FTD2XX DLL on the Windows platform.  The managed wrapper DLL (FTD2XX_NET.DLL) is provided as a free download...* here http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp.htm

Comment: You're the man! Thanks, like a charm.

Comment: @Verdolino You should post that as the answer...since it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong one. *FTDI have provided a managed .NET wrapper class for the FTD2XX DLL on the Windows platform.  The managed wrapper DLL (FTD2XX_NET.DLL) is provided as a free download...* here http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp.htm